# password_verify is not working correctly

Tags: php

i know there are a lot of threads out here with the same issue.
But everything seems to be correct.

I am hasing a password with:

```
password_hash($passwort, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

and write it in the database.
The column has 255 characters. My hash got 60, like normal.

On the login page i try to get the verify working with:

```
 if (password_verify('test', $user['passwort'])) {
```

test is for debuging, it's the input password.

```
var_dump(password_verify('test', $user['passwort']));
```

Var_dump is returning false. The $user['passwort'] includes the right string without any empty characters or something.

Any ideas?

Thank ya!

Comment: [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) requires a hash (from [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)) and the raw value from user input, using "test" is not a hash and as such, won't work

Comment: password_verify, looks if the entered password send via $_POST is correct with the hash from the database. You can't verify the word 'test' with the password that has been put in, Since test is not an hash.

Comment: Param 1 is the test password entered by the user. Parameter 2 is supposed to be the hash of the password you made on registration and stored in the database

Comment: @Rick_Jellema But its also not working if i hash the post passwort before i verify

Comment: Paul: Read the accepted answer on the Duplicate Question. That should point you in the right direction

Comment: @RiggsFolly I did. var_dump(password_verify($_POST['passwort'], $user['passwort'])); Is not working. I think i missunderstand something huge. The function needs one clear password(first) and one hashed(last).

Comment: @Paul01 `password_verify($PasswordFromLoginForm, $HashFromDatabase);`
You login with a username and password, Get the record of the user from the database with the username, then check the hashed password from that record against the password which has been put in.

Comment: @Rick_Jellema Nothing else i do. I rly dont understand whats the problem.. $user['passwort'] is my database hashed password.

Comment: Read [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) in the manual.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I did like 30 times now. Okey, then i think i have to stop this for today. Thanks anyway.